# てくる appended to a verb can mean go and come

Tags: conjugations

I have heard natives saying 渡してくるto mean "go and hand over" rather then "come and hand over". I'd thought that くる means to come and 行くmeans to go. So literal translation should theoretically give "come and hand over", which in English is wrong. The question is, why use くる instead of いく?

Comment: Does this help? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/43842/9831

Comment: @Chocolate Couldn't ask for a better answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I have heard natives saying 渡してくるto mean "go and hand over" rather then "come and hand over".

Usually in Japanese either くる or いく are relative to the position of the speaker, but if someone is talking about someone coming to them to hand something over they would say 渡しに来る not 渡してくる, because in 渡してくる the time order is 渡す followed by 来る, not the other way around.

> So literal translation should theoretically give "come and hand over", which in English is wrong. The question is, why use くる instead of いく?

No, 渡してくる would mean "hand (something) over and then come (to the speaker) after that".