# How to use the verb 連れて~

Tags: word-usage

I always have trouble in expressing myself using the word “連れて”. I know it means “to bring” but I cannot express the meaning like “someone brings me to somewhere.”

So what are the situations that the below forms are being used?

1. 連れていく
2. 連れてくる
3. 連れて行ってもらう
4. 連れて行ってくれる
5. 連れられる

I suppose in (1)(2) I am the person who brings something to somewhere while in (3)(4)(5) I am being brought to somewhere by someone?

Comment: This seems more of an issue with understanding the differences between いく・くる, and ～てもらう・～てくれる.

Answer (score 1):

The following should essentially answer your question.

- [Differences between くれます, もらいます and いただきます](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/260/45489)
- [What does ワインを買っていくよ mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/43837/45489)

---

1. 連れていく
2. 連れてくる

If 私 is the subject, 私 is the bringer and the object is the bringee. The difference 連れていく/連れてくる should generally be the same as standalone いく/くる.

3. 連れて行ってもらう

Here it depends more on the context. It can be a contraction of one of the following.

- (私が)私を連れて行ってもらう - I have someone take me to somewhere
- 私が子供を連れて行ってもらう - I have someone take my child to somewhere

In the former you are taken somewhere, and in the latter your child.

4. 連れて行ってくれる

Since the subject cannot be *I* here, you are right that you are always the object and the one who is brought to somewhere.

5. 連れられる

Generally same as 5, this means a simple passive *I'm brought by someone*, so you are the bringee.